# What if I need to differentiate 0 from NULL in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, null, return-value, function-definition

** Please don't criticize the purpose of the code itself. It's from Pat Morin's Open Data Structures book. Not my first choice, its assigned reading/practice. I just wanted to know if there is a way to differentiate, or a better way to go about this. Textbook--> http://opendatastructures.org/ods-cpp/**

** Another note: I'm coming from Java, where this would be allowed. My code still compiles, it just "fixes" it**

I'm surprised nothing like this has come up before because it seems like such a simple question. Perhaps it's buried or I'm not using the correct terminology.

I have a for loop that goes through the data in a vector. I need to return the value being searched for if it's found. What if it's not found? Here is my code.

```
int find(int x) {
    for(int i=0;i<bag.size();i++){
        // if x is equal to data, return data
        if (bag[i]==x){
            return bag[i]; // ends loop as soon as one instance is found
        }
    }
    // if we made it this far, no match was found.
    return NULL;

}
```

Pretty simple. Let's say 0 is one of the valid values that I might need to record and search for. As it is, it actually returns 0, not "NULL". Research says it is one and the same. How can I specify or differentiate? Other than returning an obsqure number that won't come up in the program because we may not always have that luxury (like -1 or -9999999). For example, searching for your account balance. No number is impossible.

Comment: If you find x (passed as parameter), what is the point in returning the same value passed as parameter ? Why not use a `bool` as returned value instead ?

Comment: `NULL` is not meant to be an `int` => code is wrong anyways. As error value for search methods, `-1` is usual.

Comment: Do I understand right that if the value is found, the function returns the same value as it gets as input? If yes, you simply have to return any other number and the calling code will be able to know if it was found or not. Or even better, just make it return true or false.

Comment: If you read my notes deviantfan, youll see that I already addressed this. You can return null in some other languages so I left it as is for clarity of intent.

@tobi303 - it's from a practice question in the textbook. Don't get me started on the textbook. This is why I'm asking here and not on my uni forum.

Comment: This is a question people migrating from other languages might have, stated reasonably, no reason to downvote

Comment: Gotta love question shamers. Yes yes yes. You're better than I am. I understand. Can you answer my question anyways? Haha. Thank you @GlennTeitelbaum. I feel a little better!

Comment: Not really c++ or trivial but if you analyse the asm code and set a data execution breakpoint to the instruction where the register holding the return value gets cleared by getting xor'ed by itself you would know you did not find anything. That is if the compiler does translate (is that the correct term?) it that way. Also possible this happens more often throughout a function so you also cannot be sure if it is about the return value. But still you could analyse instructions further and if you are about to return, check whether the register got set with the content of an address, plain value,

Comment: Or simply got cleared.

Comment: Nah screw that... You can however "return (bag[i]^0x80000000);" and in the calling function: "int ret = bla(); if (ret == NULL) notfound(); else ret ^= 0x80000000;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the function in several ways

```
bool find( int x ) 
{
    std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0;

    while (  i < bag.size() && bag[i] != x ) i++;

    return i != bag.size();
}
```

Or

```
std::vector<int>::size_type find( int x ) 
{
    std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0;

    while (  i < bag.size() && bag[i] != x ) i++;

    return i;
}
```

Or

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

std::vector<int>::iterator find( int x ) 
{
    return std::find( beg.begin(), bag.end(), x );
}
```

And use the functions correspondingly the following ways

```
if ( find( x ) ) { /*...*/ }

if ( find( x ) != bag.size() ) { /*...*/ }

if ( find( x ) != bag.end() ) { /*...*/ }
```

As for your general question in the title of the post

> What if I need to differentiate 0 from NULL in C++?

then you need fo use `nullptr` instead of NULL that to differentiate 0 from NULL.:)

Comment: It would make sense to show the algo way first to encourage using stl instead of writing your own loops

Comment: @Glenn Teitelbaum Maybe now for him it is more important to write the function himself as an exersize.:)

Answer (score 8):

Why would you return the value you are searching for from a find function? You already know the value, its the one you passed to the function. Return the position of the found element instead, as this information is much more useful. When the value isn't found, you can return a special position, like -1. Or you can follow the model of the standard library and return the end iterator, which signifies a position that is one past the  end of the range.

Comment: It's still better to return `optional<position_t>` than to invent a special position value.

Comment: @Puppy assuming he uses Boost, which is not trivial at all.

Comment: @Puppy: No, it isn't. Why would you construct an object unnecessarily when the caller already knows the value?

Comment: @DavidHaim: Assuming that he uses Boost *or* is not too silly to find one of the thousand other optional<T> reimplementations, or simply re-implement it himself. It's the concept that matters... finding an implementation is easy. `optional` is not like `variant`, there are not ten thousand surprising implementation gotchas.

Comment: @Puppy: It's still not better. It's a completely useless piece of information. A position is something the caller can actually use.

Comment: That's pretty immaterial in this discussion, since the mechanics of `optional` are identical in both cases. You're right that it arguably should be an optional position or something instead of the value itself in the optional, but that's another completely separate matter.

Comment: @Puppy: Okay, you mean returning an optional holding the position. I thought you meant an optional holding the searched for value.

Comment: @Benjamin: It wasn't explicitly stated, but I said `optional<position_t>`. I mean, the mechanics of optionality are the same regardless of returning a position, an iterator, or a value.

Comment: The useful piece of information in this case is "was the search successful?"  In that case, why not drop the 'optional' argument and just return `bool`?

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley: I would return the value I'm searching for because that's what the assignment question calls for. I would have just made it bool if it were my call. But I ask because in the real world most functions are not necessarily so simple. Returning the position seems like a really clean solution though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define XOR_MSB(x) (x^0x80000000)

int find(bool found) {
    return found ? XOR_MSB(0) : NULL;
}

int main()
{
    int value = find(false);
    if (value == NULL) printf("not found\n");
    else printf("%d\n", XOR_MSB(value));
    value = find(true);
    if (value == NULL) printf("not found\n");
    else printf("%d\n", XOR_MSB(value));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you're talking about an evil practice, coming from Java and C# developers where you can return `null` as invalid result.

well, you can't do it in C++.
Java and C# declares almost everything on the heap, and accessing objects is done done always by the reference. this means you always return a pointer from a function, and you can always return a null as a return value.

this is not so possible in C++ when a function does not return a pointer. for example , the function `std::string returnString()` can't return null as a return value.

more over, you *should not* return null as invalid output. this is wrong on so many levels even in C# and Java! if your function fails, simply throw an exception, or make your return value be passed as reference-argument and make the function return true or false.

you can also find less-agressive solutions like returning -1 (like `indexOf()` in javascript) or return somthing like `std::string::npos` or `std::vector:end` which are more C++ STL tuned.

Comment: None of those are really the right answer. Returning `null` for "not found" can be fine depending on your use case (in Java or C#). Stuff like `indexOf()`, `std::string::npos` and friends are all terrible because they're not generic. `std::vector::end` is marginally less bad since it is generic but only in a particular way.

Answer (score -2):

This is what `boost::optional<T>` is for. Effectively, this type represents "There may be a `T`, but there may not be a `T`". The user may check if there is a `T` or not. Ideally you would not depend on any special value of `T` but use an `optional<T>` instead. `optional<T>` is fully generic and may apply to pretty much any `T` you may need to use, it does not depend on some special value or state of `T`.

```
boost::optional<int> find(int x) {
    for(int i=0;i<bag.size();i++){
        // if x is equal to data, return data
        if (bag[i]==x){
            return bag[i]; // ends loop as soon as one instance is found
        }
    }
    // if we made it this far, no match was found.
    return boost::none;    
}
int main() {
    if (auto opt = find(5))
        std::cout << *opt;
}
```

Do not ever use `NULL`, it is a terrible thing. Always use `nullptr` which is substantially safer and one of the reasons why it is safer is because your wrong code would not compile.

Comment: I find it amusing that you sing the praises of `boost::optional`, but conveniently forget that it creates "overhead" at the call site which you failed to consider in `main` whatsoever, resulting in potentially buggy code.

Comment: try to use basics instead of other libraries which contain boost::optional type of keyword.